# Can's select between two "select" statements

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need to do statement

```
SELECT data from result_orders
```

only if **order_state** is NULL.

Else I need to do another select statment.

I try this but get error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 15:  WHEN order_state IS NULL THEN SELECT data from result_order...




SELECT
CASE data
 WHEN order_state IS NULL THEN SELECT data from result_orders
 ELSE select data from result_orders
END 
FROM result_orders
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union here, something like:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT data
    FROM result_orders
    WHERE order_state IS NULL
)

SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM result_orders WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) = 0;
```

In the event that the first query in the union does have records, the second query would return nothing.  Should the first query have no records, then the second query would return records if that query matches anything.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
WHEN order_state IS NULL THEN SELECT data from result_order
```

is in the wrong syntax it should look like this

```
 SELECT ISNULL(order_state, result_order)
```

this means when order_state is null return result_order

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 13: SELECT ISNULL(order_state, data FROM result_order)

Comment: @a_subscriber try this, sorry I'm pretty new to sql.

Comment: ERROR:  column "order_state" does not exist
LINE 13: SELECT ISNULL(order_state, result_order)